# new form - edit form -display form load very slowly

Tags: infopath, custom-list, edit-form, infopath-rules, newform

we have large  custom list in sharepoint 2013. these items are around 10000.
recently new,edit,display form loaded slowly. forms take a long time to load, about near 2 minutes.
forms customized with infopath 2013, they have two lookup column, one people picker column and 5 other fields.

Please help me figure out how to speed up the load times on this

Comment: You are exceeding sharepoint list items limit which is 5000 items per list. If you exceed the limit, yet increasing the threshold. The performance of sharepoint site degrades. Hence it is not recomended.

Answer (score 1):

What I suggest is do not run the Data Connections lookups on load and try using a query to minimize the return results. When you used a query the data connection, set the fields that you only need the results.

Comment: HP DL380 Dual CPU, 16 GB RAM

Comment: Thank you, my problem is resolved! that`s about infopath data connection.